# Mongoengine - command find requires authentication

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am new to using Mongoengine with an authenticated MongoDB.

I have a Mongo Database called 'gambit_test'. I have enabled authentication on it and I have a proper user that can I authenticate into the database to perform read and write.

I created the user for 'gambit_test' using the following command in Mongo Client:

```
use gambit_test
db.createUser({
    user: "gambit_admin",
    pwd: "xxxxxx",
    roles:[{role: "userAdmin" , db:"admin"}]
})
```

When I log into MongoDB to check my user status, I use a command as follows (logging in as a super admin):

```
mongo -u sup_admin -p yyyyyyyy
```

To verify my user status, here is what I run:

```
use gambit_test
show users
```

It returns the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "gambit_test.gambit_admin",
    "user" : "gambit_admin",
    "db" : "gambit_test",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "gambit_test"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbAdmin",
            "db" : "gambit_test"
        }
    ],
    "mechanisms" : [
        "SCRAM-SHA-1",
        "SCRAM-SHA-256"
    ]
}
```

Inside my Python `test.py` code, here is what I am doing:

```
from mongoengine import *

class History(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        connect('gambit_test')
        History.objects().get()
    except Exception as e: 
        connect(host='mongodb://gambit_admin:xxxxxx@localhost' + 
        ':27017/gambit_test')
        History.objects().get()
```

When I try to run the above python code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    History.objects().get()
  File "/home/ubuntu/gambit/genv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 267, in get
    result = six.next(queryset)
  File "/home/ubuntu/gambit/genv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1484, in __next__
    raw_doc = six.next(self._cursor)
  File "/home/ubuntu/gambit/genv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1189, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/ubuntu/gambit/genv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1104, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/home/ubuntu/gambit/genv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 982, in __send_message
    helpers._check_command_response(first)
  File "/home/ubuntu/gambit/genv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 155, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
  pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command find requires authentication
```

I have no clue why this is happening. The reason is I can perform normal find() and insert() using Mongo client. But, when I use Mongoengine, things break...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you try to connect using the terminal, specify the authentication database to connect smoothly. `mongo -u "gambit_admin" -p "pwd" YOURHOSTIP --authenticationDatabase "gambit_test"`

Comment: Adding information with reference to my first comment : You can skip the `YOURHOSTIP` if you are connecting to localhost.

Answer (score 1):

For further reference, issue got fixed (https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2010)
The problem was that the second `connect` call wasn't overwriting the `default` connection set by the first call, it was just silently ignored